# IntelliJ IDEA using selenium and TestNG, "Test framework quit unexpectedly" message

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

I am doing a selenium course and wrote a very simple code to test IntelliJ, selenium and TestNG, I already installed the jar files for selenium and TestNG, but every time I start the code it gives me the message "Test framework quit unexpectedly".

```
package com.example;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test {

    @Test
    void initialTest(){
        System.out.println("Initial test OK");
    }
}
```

[this is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQrVC.png)

Comment: You can copy the error here, so this question is easier to read.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest IntelliJ version, and then from the main menu, select File > Invalidate Caches / Restart. That seems to be a recurring issue https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Test+framework+quit+unexpectedly